# Find a specific character in a row and read it?

Tags: r

I've got a little problem with this. The header of each file I have looks like this:

```
*COUNTRY : US                                     *
***************************************************
*CAPITAL : Washington, D.C, district of columbia  *
*Language: English                                *  
***************************************************
V1 V2 V3
```

Then comes my data variables below (V1,V2,...). What I want to do is to take only the language from each file (English, French, Spanish...) and put it in my plot script. Because when I was reading the files I do skip these rows in `read.table`, otherwise `read.table` wouldn't work. Hope you understood my issue.

Comment: I would read them twice.  Once to get the language: `readLines(foo, n=1)` and again for the data: `read.table(foo, header=TRUE, sep='\t', skip=5)`... Or I don't understand your question.  If you can provide some of the code you've tried and how it doesn't meet your needs you'll get a much better answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
## File name
filename <- "/tmp/temp.txt"
## Read the 5 first lines
header <- readLines(filename, n=5)
## Grep the language field in these lines
result <- grep("^\\*Language: .*$", header, value=TRUE)
## Extract the language string
sub("^\\*Language: ", "", result)
```

Note that if the Language field is always on the 4th line, you can simply do :

```
filename <- "/tmp/temp.txt"
header <- readLines(filename, n=4)
sub("^\\*Language: ", "", header[4])
```

Comment: What i wanna do is to take only the word "English" outta the whole row instead. But that's alright thank you :)

Comment: @user2207085 That's what my answer do : the last line will only return "English".

Comment: yes you are right that's what i got "English    *" I forgot to add that i got stars at the end of eachline(look up my post), how can i remove it? thank you

Comment: Try `sub("^\\*Language: (.*?) .*$", "\\1", result)`

Answer (score 1):

I would open a [file](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/connections.html) connection, read the header data, and then proceed with [read.table](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to read the rest of the file. This way, you only read the file once. Something like this:

```
f <- file( "data.txt", open = "r" )
language <- NULL
while( TRUE ){
    line <- readLines( f, 1L )
    if( grepl( "*Language: ", line ) ){
        language <- sub( "*Language: (.[*])", "\\1", line )    
    }
    if( !is.null(language) && grepl("^[*][*]", line) ) break
}
read.table( f, header = TRUE )
close( f )
```